# How to get the picked value from a uiOutput server side in shiny

Tags: shiny, modal-dialog, dt

I have a dialog that I need to create in the server side because is a dialog that I embed in a DT.

The reason why I create this question is because I have in my dialog the following:

```
observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Select location:",
      uiOutput('select.file'),

      # plotOutput("plot"),
      easyClose = TRUE
    ))
})
```

and I embed the row of dialog as the following:

```
newrow <- shinyInput(actionButton, 5, 'button_', label = "Season", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"show\",  this.id)' )
```

The problem is that when I want to do a plot to show the user how the data is, I can't because I don't know which value I've selected so far. Because of this, I can't read it as a csv and plot it.

Can someone provide me of an approach or an idea? I'm quite new to Shiny
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at example below where a chart is generated on click from Datatable.

Here you can wrap the selected row into a reactive `SelectedRow()` which then can be used to map against the row number. I have displayed the row number in the `modal` title:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

# This function will create the buttons for the datatable, they will be unique
shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {inputs <- character(len)
for (i in seq_len(len)) {
  inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))}
inputs
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('my_table'),uiOutput("popup")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  my_data <- reactive({
    testdata <- mtcars
    as.data.frame(cbind(View = shinyInput(actionButton, nrow(testdata),'button_', label = "View", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' ),testdata))
  })  
  output$my_table <- DT::renderDataTable(my_data(),selection = 'single',options = list(searching = FALSE,pageLength = 10),server = FALSE, escape = FALSE,rownames= FALSE)

  SelectedRow <- eventReactive(input$select_button,{
    as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
  })

  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    toggleModal(session, "modalExample", "open")
  })

  DataRow <- eventReactive(input$select_button,{
    my_data()[SelectedRow(),2:ncol(my_data())]
  })

  output$popup <- renderUI({
    bsModal("modalExample", paste0("Data for Row Number: ",SelectedRow()), "", size = "large",
            column(12,renderPlot(plot(mtcars))               
            )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]